# Streets recognition, deduction of severity

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to make an analysis of a set of phrases, and I don't know exactly how "natural language processing" can help me, or if someone can share his knowledge with me.

The objective is to extract streets and localizations. Often this kind of information is not presented to the reader in a structured way, and It's hard to find a way of parsing it. I have two main objectives.

First the extraction of the streets itself. As far as I know NLP libraries can help me to tokenize a phrase and perform an analysis which will get nouns (for example). But where a street begins and where does it ends?. I assume that I will need to compare that analysis with a streets database, but I don't know wich is the optimal method.

Also, I would like to deduct the level of severity , for example, in car accidents. I'm assuming that the only way is to stablish some heuristic by the present words in the phrase (for example, if deceased word appears + 100). Am I correct?

Thanks a lot as always! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first part of what you want to do ("First the extraction of the streets itself. [...] But where a street begins and where does it end?") is a subfield of NLP called [Named Entity Recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition). There are many libraries available which can do this. I like NLTK for Python myself. Depending on your choice I assume that a streetname database would be useful for training the recognizer, but you might be able to get reasonable results with the default corpus. Read the documentation for your NLP library for that.

The second part, recognizing accident severity, can be treated as an independent problem at first. You could take the raw words or their part of speech tags as features, and train a classifier on it (SVM, HMM, KNN, your choice). You would need a fairly large, correctly labelled training set for that; from your description I'm not certain you have that?

"I'm assuming that the only way is to stablish some heuristic by the present words in the phrase " is very vague, and could mean a lot of things. Based on the next sentence it kind of sounds like you think scanning for a predefined list of keywords is the only way to go. In that case, no, see the paragraph above.

Once you have both parts working, you can combine them and count the number of accidents and their severity per street. Using some geocoding library you could even generalize to neighborhoods or cities. Another challenge is the detection of synonyms ("Smith Str" vs "John Smith Street") and  homonyms ("Smith Street" in London vs "Smith Street" in Leeds).

Comment: Thank you so much Junuxx, that was more than I've expected :)